# how to split grouped array of objects(with same id) into individual array of objects using javascript

Tags: javascript

May i know how to split the arrays which are grouped.
Attached is the snapshot showing my requirement.
The grouped array objects have similar parent Id, i would want to separate them out and place them as individual array objects like the rest of the array objects.

Thanks kg

[image: snapshot]

Comment: Please update the question with sample of input and output array.

Comment: my best guess at this point is to look at Array.reduce()